Why are 2nd level tokens also showing as root tokens?
I have the following custom hook_token_info() code:
  $info['types']['sia_ind_policy'] = [
    'name' => t('SIA Individual Policy'),
    'description' => t('Policy related tokens for Individual Policy fillpdf.')
  ];

  // Lettered tokens.
  $token_set = ['Insurer', 'NAIC'];
  foreach ($token_set as $set) {
    $set_index = strtolower($set);
    $info['types'][$set_index] = ['name' => $set, 'needs-data' => 'sia_ind_policy'];
    $info['tokens']['sia_ind_policy'][$set_index] = [    // define sub group as first level token
      'name' => $set,
      'description' => t('Insurer tokens for: ' . $set),
      'type' => $set_index, // tells drupal that this token belongs to sub_group1
    ];
    foreach (range('A', 'F') as $letter) {
      $info['tokens'][$set_index][strtolower($letter)] = [
        'name' => $set . ' ' . $letter,
      ];
    }
  }

This works perfectly to give me a token structure showing in the token browser as:
SIA Individual Policy

Insurer

Insurer A
Insurer B
etc


NAIC

NAIC A
NAIC B
etc



But it also gives root/top level token groups of Insurer and NAIC. I have tried a couple dozen variations but not been able to get what I want without the additional top level clutter.

You cannot have [sia_ind_policy:Insurer:a] without [sia_ind_policy:Insurer]. That would be like having [node:created:since] without [node:created].

If memory serves, there’s no concept of token “levels”, just types and tokens. Types are always “top level” by definition, but can be chained, which provides the hierarchy. Because of that, I don’t think what you’re hoping for is achievable

@Clive, just open Token Browser, expand Node top level and you will see these for every field.

Oh right, that's not core, it's the Token contributed module. Probably should've guessed you had it installed from the rest of the description

Core has no support for this, but the contributed Token module does. Once you have it installed, add a nested key to your type definitions, e.g.
$info['types'][$set_index] = [
  'name' => $set,
  'needs-data' => 'sia_ind_policy',
  'nested' => TRUE,
];

And it won't show up on the very top level any more.

Yup, that's it. Thanks.
